# Неконсистентный перевод слияние/объединение меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, инструменты-модератора

На странице синонимов меток в переводе фильтра использовано слово "слияние", а на кнопке - "объединение". Надо бы сделать консистентно.

> [image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Обновил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12435

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.12.10.40971